# Why can't reflect-metadata be used in vite

Tags: typescript, vite, reflect-metadata

```json
import "reflect-metadata"

function validate(target: any) {
  let paramtypes = Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", target);
  console.log(paramtypes);  // undefined
}

@validate
class Log {
  constructor(public readonly xx: string) {}
}
```

Hit me to start the server, and when I opened the webpage, I found that paramtypes was undefined

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vite uses ESBuild which doesn't support `"emitDecoratorMetadata"` in tsconfig, since ESBuild doesn't have its own type system implemented. Refer to this [vitejs/vite#788](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/788) for more details on this topic.

However, there are workarounds to this issue. One approach I took was explicitly disabling ESBuild and used SWC instead. You can find more details regarding that on [this demo](https://github.com/SIGUSR97/decorator-demo/). Here is its vite config file:

```js
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import swc from "rollup-plugin-swc";

// import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        swc({
            jsc: {
                parser: {
                    syntax: "typescript",
                    // tsx: true, // If you use react
                    dynamicImport: true,
                    decorators: true,
                },
                target: "es2021",
                transform: {
                    decoratorMetadata: true,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    esbuild: false,
});
```

SWC is a fast alternative to ESBuild, having implemented its own type system, it can emit decorator metadata without any issue.

Comment: This solution is feasible

Comment: It doesn't seem to resolve css/less files correctly.

Comment: @红了樱桃绿了吧唧 I dont see how this relates to css/less files, please elaborate.

Comment: Doesn't work on my end, tested using vite 2.9.9.

Comment: this does not work anymore/has never worked

Comment: @SebastianG This worked last time I checked [my demo repo](https://github.com/zojize/decorator-demo) with vite version 2.4.0. I have no interest in updating my answer for newer vite versions since I don't use or recommend the usage of decorators anymore, so you might need to figure out your own solutions.

Comment: This doesn't work:
``error when starting dev server: TypeError: swc is not a function``

Comment: @KiddoV Like I said, I have no interest in updating my answer for newer vite/ts versions. Additionally, with Typescript 5.0, and its implementation for [Decorator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), `reflect-metadata` will only work with the legacy decorator implementation `--experimentalDecorators`. As for the swc plugin, refer to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-swc) for its usage.

Answer (score -1):

Using SWC is feasible solution, but if you want to stay closer to the original setup I've found the right configuration.

It's true that esbuild does not support decorator metadata, but! there is a community plugin for that - [@anatine/esbuild-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@anatine/esbuild-decorators).

I've added it to the optimizeBuild configuration and it Just Works™️.

From my understanding it shouldn't have worked after build (because from the docs vite does not use esbuild when building for prod), but it does work!

Here is an example repo with vite 4 & tsyringe that uses reflect-metadata
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hzkjj3?file=vite.config.ts

Comment: Thank you for providing this StackBlitz example. Do you know why error TS2322 is thrown in its vite.config.ts file?