# Testing (ExpressJS + TypeScript + Vitest): tsconfig setup not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, express, visual-studio-code, vitest

I'll just jump straight into it with an example:

I have the following (simplified) project structure:

```
src/
    app.ts
test/
    integration/
        example.spec.ts
    tsconfig.json
tsconfig.json
```

The root `tsconfig.json` contains following settings:

```json
{
  "extends":"@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

The `tsconfig.json` inside the `tests/` folder contains following settings:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["vitest/globals"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "vitest.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

Now I have basically 2 issues:

1. Running a basic example test from pnpm works with following script: `cd ./test && vitest run`. However, in vscode it doesn't seem to parse the inner tsconfig, so I'm always getting type errors inside my IDE:

[image: ide errors 1]
[image: ide errors 2]

2. Whenever I want to import `app` from the src folder, I'm getting following typeORM related errors:
   [image: app import errors]

For the first issue, I'm guessing it's either a bug in vscode or it need to be configured somewhere properly. But I couldn't find much about it.
For the second issue, I'm probably missing something (build first, run tests on that build?).

Maybe I'm trying something fundamentally wrong, but then I would like to know how to properly setup a testable ExpressJS TypeScript app.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm just assuming that `vitest` can't work with TypeORM since it needs `reflect-metadata` package and `vite` (with `esbuild` underneath) also doesn't work with this package. I'm gonna try again when we migrate away from TypeORM.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with using **SWC** instead of the default **ESBuild** as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68570844/12064793